# 12.04 crashing on Asus A9Rp?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, asus

I've got an Asus A9Rp Laptop which crashes constantly (4 to 6 crashes in 2 hours of use), in two different ways:

- Long terminal output on black screen
- Completely graphically messed up, But still running programs and responsive, But you don't see it.

First I used Ubuntu 11.10 and then clean install of 12.04 (both 32bit) via DVD but the problem persists.

I've also checked the HD via `fsck` and the memory via `memtest` for 9 hours, no errors.

Any ideas?

I am total noob, so ask me if you need more info. Is there any way to log error or should I just take a screen shot?

Both crashes happened when installing something, But I had the similar crashes when surfing the Internet/office programs.

[Here are photos of the output; first two pictures are one crash and the two others another one](http://imageshack.us/g/29/20120502005.jpg/)

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: i had got 1,5 GB ram inside, while the laptop just recognized 1 GB due to hw/bios limitations. so i took the 512 mb out and it runs completely stable.

btw: windows xp ran stable under same conditions. ;) 
(but linux is still faster)